# Download POST method's PDF response using retrofit 2

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2, httpresponse

I am new to android and JSON using retrofit. I am using retrofit 2 with my project.
This is one of post API and it gives a pdf as the response.

```
@POST("examples/campaign_report_new.php")
Call<ResponseBody> getAddressTrackingReport(@Body ModelCredentialsAddressTracking credentials);
```

I used the below code to do this function and I stuck in the response method to download and show that pdf.

```
private void downloadPdf() { 
ModelCredentialsAddressTracking
    credentials = new ModelCredentialsAddressTracking(campaign,
    dateFrom, dateTo);            
                ApiService apiService = RetroClient.getApiService();
                Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getAddressTrackingReport(credentials);            
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.body().bytes()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }            
                        boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());            
                    }            
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
            });
        }
```

Below link is the response I got from Postman:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC50Z.png)

writeResponseBodyToDisk() function :

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
    try {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "Door Tracker");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("door tracker", "Oops! Failed create "
                        + "door tracker" + " directory");
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "AddressTrackingReport "+ timeStamp + ".pdf");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
            }

            outputStream.flush();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Somebody, please help a solution. This may contain errors Because I am new to it.Thanks.

Comment: Could you show how would the response body look like ? I also think that you will have to define your own response type `Call<MyResponseType>`

Comment: You are giving runtime permissions ?

Comment: @ABDevelopers , I gave external permission

Comment: Add your writeResponseBodyToDisk code and also your response.

Comment: I updated my question with your needfull, @ABDevelopers

Comment: Did you check the response.body()? I mean is it null or any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API using `form-data` as input, So change `@Body` to `@Multipart` Type. This will give you a response. Add below snippet inside `onResponse()`

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {

progressDialog.dismiss();

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
     boolean writtenToDisk = false;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(AddressTrackingActivity.this,
                        response.body());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Asynch Excep : ", e);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "file download was a success? " + writtenToDisk);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (writtenToDisk) {
                String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/Door Tracker/" + fileName;
                Log.d(TAG, "file name : " + fileName);
                File file = new File(pdfPath);
                Uri bmpUri;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
                    bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Log.d(TAG, "bmpUri : " + bmpUri);
                } else {
                    bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddressTrackingActivity.this,
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

                    Log.d(TAG, "bmpUri : " + bmpUri);
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(bmpUri, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ActivityNotFoundException : ", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();
} else {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(AddressTrackingActivity.this, "Network error, Please retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "server contact failed");
}
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = "";
boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body(),fileName);
    if(writtenToDisk){
     String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Door Tracker/"+fileName;
     File file = new File(pdfPath);
     Uri bmpUri;
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
         bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
     } else {
          bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
     }

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setDataAndType(bmpUri, "application/pdf");
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      try {
              startActivity(intent);
      }
       catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

       }
    }
```

Just get the File Name from method writeResponseBodyToDisk :

```
 File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "AddressTrackingReport "+ timeStamp + ".pdf");

 fileName = mediaFile.getName();
```

Just Debug and Check your file name is correct.

Comment: This solution gives a file with an empty body. I can convert the `response` to that pdf.

Comment: Check with your response data from your server and post the log of your response.body and also check the filename is proper. If server data is coming proper than this code should work'