# How to download PDF using Retrofit 2 POST method?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to download PDF using the Retrofit 2 POST method. 
Part with retrofit request and response is ok, I got the PDF file in response in this form:

```
1 0 obj
    [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
    endobj
    13 0 obj
    << /Length 1600 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream
    x��X�nSG�_�w�����K���BmD q�D�K|�:q�:�Jy�>B���̜�o
```

Here is function to save response to file([From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940121/download-post-methods-pdf-response-using-retrofit-2)):

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
    try {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "Door Tracker");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("door tracker", "Oops! Failed create "
                        + "door tracker" + " directory");
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "AddressTrackingReport "+ timeStamp + ".pdf");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);

            while (true) {
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                Log.d(TAG, "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
            }

            outputStream.flush();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
door tracker: "Oops! Failed to create door tracker directory"
```

I have tried some other solutions offered in this question, but I have not succeeded. So I get a good response but I can't save it to my phone. Also to mention I added a user-permission for that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Why are you posting download code and Retrofit code if your problem is only creating a directory? You could better try to create a directory before trying to download as then you can cancel the download. And you forgot to `return;` where mkdirs() failed. Also you could display a Toast() to inform the user of your app. Are you on Android Q?

Comment: Create the required directories before checking the existence. If you're using Android M (API 23) or above, asking for run-time permission for storage access is mandatory (you just asked it in manifest file). You didn't mention the Android version in your question. And also as @blackapps said I don't think it's related to Retrofit networking library related problem.